# Reopen good, but duplicate, question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

[This post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288405/is-testable-code-better-code/288411?noredirect=1#comment597093_288411) was closed as a duplicate, which perhaps it is, but the original question contains a single answer that doesn't really add much to the question. The recent, duplicate question has many more answers and has generated much discussion.

So, is there a case for closing the original question and keeping the new one seeing as the quality is significantly different between the two?

Comment: your note about _much discussion_ may be considered as point in favor of keeping it closed, see  **[On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)**

Comment: @gnat much discussion may be bad, and a lot of it was moved to chat anyway but - it has many more good answers than the original, which is what I was more concerned about. We're keeping a poor question and closing a good one because of their age, not their quality.

Comment: many answers make me suspect that it's [too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490). Asker just dropped word "better" and didn't attempt to clarify despite requests for this in comments (guess they're not really motivated, because upvotes from [hot list lemmings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224750/165773) can make one feel it's okay as is)...

Comment: ...frankly, when I voted for a duplicate, it didn't have answers, and I thought that better-as-stable is the only reasonable interpretation. But now, looking at so many different answers twisting it in so many different ways, I somehow feel that too broad could be a more appropriate close reason